# "[ilist]" this tag for replacement

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I nominate [ilist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ilist) for a synonym with [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list). I don't see any significant reasons to have the interface as a separate tag.

Comment: There's only 33 instances of it.. i'd suggest retagging them with list

Comment: i get 297 instances.

Comment: Ahh.. right I was on "unanswered".  Still, not very many I'd say the tag is really more meaningless really,

Comment: Jon Skeet will lose a tag badge, but I guess that's just how it goes.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom No, because he only has 18 answers, so no badge.